# Update to 64bit version google play

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-console-developer

How to update version google play required to 64 bit version on android studio

All new apps and app updates are required to provide 64-bit versions of any 32-bit native code they provide.
Extension: Google Play will continue to accept 32-bit only updates to existing games that use Unity 5.6 or older until August 2021.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see stated here you have to follow the steps : [Android Developers Blog.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html)

> **Update** : [Ensure that your app supports 64-bit devices](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)